# How to access application on web browser while using AKS with Istio as add-on

Tags: azure-aks, istio, servicemesh

I am using AKS with Istio add on feature and tried to deploy the application and in the end I am to curl my application(Followed this MS article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/istio-deploy-ingress). Also from the same vm I can access my AKS cluster too. Now my doubts are:

1. How can I access my application from the browser, just like we used to access in case of ingress.
2. How can we setup the SSL/TLS certificate for my application.

Earlier though that it could be the problem with the ports, then I tried to add HTTP port 80 also but it did not help.